# relation and dependency between md and xs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new and working with bootstrap. My work is responsive in md, but in xs it is breaking. My question is how xs work relative to md and how should I put grid value to make it adjust? I am giving md and xs both in class. Sample code :-

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
   <img src="xstatic/images/google-play-download.png" width="60%"   style="margin-bottom:7px"><br>    
   <img src="xstatic/images/download-via-sms.png" width="60%" style="margin-bottom:7px"><br> 
   <img src="xstatic/images/apple-image.png" width="60%" style="margin-bottom:7px"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: What type of layout are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Images are horizontally from Desktop but vertically in md. But in xs, it is not responsive, some parts are going out of screen. I want to keep it same as it is showing in md, but the size will decrease automatically, as per screen size. So, that it can fit in very small screen.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want the images to wrap on smaller screens and avoid wrap from medium sized.

Comment: yeah. I want to wrap on smaller and medium sized both. It will depend on screen. If screen is medium/small then it will adjust as per screen resolution.

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Please create a demo or illustrate using images.

Comment: Whatever, I am seeing in md, I want to see the same in xs too. That means, in xs it has to be smaller size automatically to fit in the screen. The same column and their position should be same in xs too. But I am adding col-sx-* it is overlapping between two columns. But in col-md-* it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your question, but I think your trouble may be with the padding on the col classes at xs?

Try removing the padding/margin on the container

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'>
```